# Rails can't create new object inside of ActiveAdmin controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm working on messaging system between `User` and `AdminUser`. The `User` part is ready now I'm struggling how to allow `Admin` to send a reply to a conversation started by a `User`, inside of ActiveAdmin.

Code below:

```
# app/admin/conversations.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Conversation do
 decorate_with ConversationDecorator

# ...

  controller do
    def show
      super
      @message = @conversation.messages.build
    end
  end
end

app/views/admin/conversations/_show.html.erb
# ...
  <%= form_for [@conversation, @message] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
    <%= f.text_field :messageable_id, value: current_user.id, type: "hidden" %>
    <%= f.text_field :messageable_type, value: "#{current_user.class.name}", type: "hidden" %>
    <%= f.submit "Send Reply" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Which gives me an error:

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
> Extracted source (around line #51):
> 51 <%= form_for [@conversation, @message] do |f| %>

When I tried to debug it turned out `@message = nil` inside of `_show.html.erb`. How is that possible if I defined @message inside of ActiveAdmin controller ?

[EDIT]

In case you're curious, ConversationController below:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @admins = AdminUser.all
    @conversations = Conversation.all
  end

  def new
    @conversation = Conversation.new
    @conversation.messages.build
  end

  def create
    @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)

    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
  end
end

#routes
  resources :conversations do
    resources :messages
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you set up instance variables in your controller, and then Rails later does an *implicit* render of the view once the controller method completes.

However, it is possible to do an *explicit* render of the view, by calling something like `render action:` or `render template:` while the controller method is running, and presumably this is happening within the call to `super`.

See the [Layout and Rendering Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more information.

You'll need to move the assignment to be before the call to `super`.

You may also need to replace `@conversation` with `resource` in the ActiveAdmin controller (this is an ActiveAdmin/InheritedResources gem thing).

Comment: Well with one thing you're right - assignment should be before the `super`. But even if I did this I still have `@message = nil` error. Monkey solution is to declare conversation as `def show;  @current_conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id]);  @message = @current_conversation.messages.build;   super` and it works. But I don't think I should do this

Comment: @mr_muscle That's exactly the same `@message` assignment you had before except on a different variable. I highly doubt one gave nil and the other worked - build is not going to return nil. I can believe one gave a NilClass UndefinedMethodError because `@conversation` was nil, but I already covered using `resource` in my post.

Comment: Also restart your server as AA doesn't always reload code properly in my experience.

Comment: That's right, the problem is inside `@conversation` therefore I declare it explicitly - my mistake. If I replace `@conversation` by `resource` it doesn't change anything, still the same error. Server restart, spring stop won't work either.

Comment: @mr_muscle Those two things should be equivalent. The source code for the `resource` method is here:
https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources/blob/b7bb90e756d7af11a9bf8d1878dfcc5a271b30a4/lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb#L44
Unless you have previously set `@conversation` or overridden the association chain it'll be the same thing.

Comment: @mr_muscle If it's still not working, I can only suggest putting in breakpoints to see what's happening.

Comment: Oh shit, the issue was inside of my view file. All I had to do was to change `@conversation` to `resource` and see if `@message` exist in view.